# Install and uninstall a java application in ms-windows

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have created a java application.
I also created another java application which install the first application.
The program runs perfectly.
However the program isn't displayed in control panel->programs.

I also want to create an uninstaller (let's say unintaller.bat). But i want to works like any other uninstaller. When someone goes to Control Panel->serach program->uninstall this program it will run the uninstaller.bat

In other words, the concept is how to declare the java application in windows...

Any idea???

Comment: You'll need to be able to write to the Windows registry. You might consider having a look at the available installers, things like install4j or izPack for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing an application doesn't necessarily mean registering it with the operating system. For example, for a Mac, I can open an App without having it added to the Applications folder.

Same with Windows. Just because a new file can be added to the Start menu, it doesn't mean it was registered.

Use a Windows installer. There are tons that are open source, and even MS provides a free one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288.
This will allow you to install an uninstall an application using standard tools. Yes. It can be called from a bat file.

Java open source installers: http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators